# On error goto inside an if, does it react to any error on the sub?

Tags: vba, goto

I have a question about the `On Error GoTo`. I have this line of code

```
    If CheckF = 0 Then
        On Error GoTo Error_handler
        .PivotItems(.PivotItems(pivotcount).name).Visible = False


    End If
```

My question is that if I have an error outside that `if` it trigger the `On Error` anyway

And if that is the case, I would like to have a way to avoid it, because I need a different kind of message for each different error.

I hope I explained myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, anything executed after the `On Error` statement will go to the error handler label, even after the `End If` statement. If you want to turn off this error handler you need to reset it as follows:

```
If CheckF = 0 Then
    On Error GoTo Error_handler
    .PivotItems(.PivotItems(pivotcount).name).Visible = False
    On Error GoTo 0
End If
```

Comment: If I do that, and the `Error_handler` triggers the `On Error Goto 0` is not going to activate right?

Comment: `On Error GoTo 0` turns off any error handling. VBA will just stop at the line where error is encountered (as it usually does). You can do that in `Error_handler`, but it is wrong way to do it. In `Error_handler` you should use `Resume` or go to another label. It is good practice to either turn on error handling for entire sub and handle all errors, or turn the error handling on and off "at the same level" - aka like in my example above.

Comment: Looks like the [On Error Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3211/error-handling#t=201701111543262206472) documentation needs to mention this :-)

Answer (score 0):

Only if the if-clause is executed.
With `On Error GoTo 0` you can turn off your error handler at the end of the if-clause.

Comment: can you elaborate it a little bit? I don't get how it works